# Why does TinyMCE in Django admin output HTML tags?

Tags: django, tinymce

I have two apps using the same [TinyMCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE) textarea configurations. However, while an input in an app does output the text properly, the same input in another app does not output the text properly -it outputs the `<p> <li>` tags, etc.

I have exactly the same Django source code for these two different apps. As I mentioned above, two apps using the same TinyMCE textarea. How come this could happen?

Comment: impossible to answer given your information here. you should at least put all relevant parts of admin.py and models.py somewhere for us to read.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you are using the template filter `safe`, like this `{{ value|safe }}` so it doesn't show the HTML code from TinyMCE.

More info [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe):

Comment: Example if you have the next var = New.description, change {{value|safe }} for {{ New.description|safe}}