# Django Admin Area "TextField" replacement. Issue with greek characters

Tags: django, textfield

I have replaced the standard Django "TextField" field with TinyMCE, CKEditor and Froala.
When I type a greek word inside the editors (all of them) in the Admin Area, the result in the frontend app is HTML codes.
For example, I type my name **Αδριανός** and I see **`<p>&Alpha;&delta;&rho;&iota;&alpha;&nu;ό&sigmaf;</p>`**

I use Postgres with encoding=UTF8, Collate=English_United States.1253, CType=English_United States.1253

Answer (score 0):

Seems similar to this issue:
[Why does TinyMCE in Django admin output HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889080/why-does-tinymce-in-django-admin-output-html-tags)

You need to set your default encoding to `raw` in your TinyMCE configs

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'entity_encoding': 'raw',
    . . . 
}
```

For CKEditor, and anything else you just need a way to mark the text entity as `safe` as you would in any templatel, ie. `{{ greek_unicode_entity_string | safe }}`

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/configuration/Configuration3x@entity_encoding/

Comment: Great! Works! Thanks!!

Comment: glad I could help!